# Media Player sample app crash

Tags: java, android

I am writing an app and When I try to load the class/layout by pressing a button on my main menu, I get the following logcat errors and I do not know what they mean, can anyone tell me why my app is crashing?

```
03-11 16:40:06.955: E/AndroidRuntime(18456): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-11 16:40:06.955: E/AndroidRuntime(18456): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.famouspeople/com.example.famouspeople.Music}: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.example.famouspeople.Music; no empty constructor
03-11 16:40:06.955: E/AndroidRuntime(18456):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2024)
03-11 16:40:06.955: E/AndroidRuntime(18456):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
03-11 16:40:06.955: E/AndroidRuntime(18456):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
03-11 16:40:06.955: E/AndroidRuntime(18456):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
03-11 16:40:06.955: E/AndroidRuntime(18456):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-11 16:40:06.955: E/AndroidRuntime(18456):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-11 16:40:06.955: E/AndroidRuntime(18456):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
03-11 16:40:06.955: E/AndroidRuntime(18456):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-11 16:40:06.955: E/AndroidRuntime(18456):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-11 16:40:06.955: E/AndroidRuntime(18456):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
03-11 16:40:06.955: E/AndroidRuntime(18456):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
03-11 16:40:06.955: E/AndroidRuntime(18456):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-11 16:40:06.955: E/AndroidRuntime(18456): Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.example.famouspeople.Music; no empty constructor
03-11 16:40:06.955: E/AndroidRuntime(18456):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
03-11 16:40:06.955: E/AndroidRuntime(18456):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
03-11 16:40:06.955: E/AndroidRuntime(18456):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1057)
03-11 16:40:06.955: E/AndroidRuntime(18456):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2015)
03-11 16:40:06.955: E/AndroidRuntime(18456):    ... 11 more
03-11 16:40:16.560: I/Process(18456): Sending signal. PID: 18456 SIG: 9
```

Code:

```
public class Music implements OnCompletionListener{
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
boolean isPrepared = false;

public Music(AssetFileDescriptor assetDescriptor){
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    try{
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(assetDescriptor.getFileDescriptor(), assetDescriptor.getStartOffset(), assetDescriptor.getLength());
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
        isPrepared = true;
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    } catch(Exception ex){
        throw new RuntimeException("Couldn't load music, uh oh!");
    }
}

public Music(FileDescriptor fileDescriptor){
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    try{
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(fileDescriptor);
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
        isPrepared = true;
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    } catch(Exception ex){
        throw new RuntimeException("Couldn't load music, uh oh!");
    }
}

public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
    synchronized(this){
        isPrepared = false;
    }
}

public void play() {
    if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
        return;
    }
    try{
        synchronized(this){
            if(!isPrepared){
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
            }
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
    } catch(IllegalStateException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch(IOException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void stop() {
    mediaPlayer.stop();
    synchronized(this){
        isPrepared = false;
    }
}

public void switchTracks(){
    mediaPlayer.seekTo(0);
    mediaPlayer.pause();
}

public void pause() {
    mediaPlayer.pause();
}

public boolean isPlaying() {
    return mediaPlayer.isPlaying();
}

public boolean isLooping() {
    return mediaPlayer.isLooping();
}

public void setLooping(boolean isLooping) {
    mediaPlayer.setLooping(isLooping);
}

public void setVolume(float volumeLeft, float volumeRight) {
    mediaPlayer.setVolume(volumeLeft, volumeRight);
}

public void dispose() {
    if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
        stop();
    }
    mediaPlayer.release();
}
```

}

Comment: 1) This isn't helpful? *`can't instantiate class com.example.famouspeople.Music; no empty constructor`* 2) Add your code if you still can't figure it out.

Comment: you don't know what 'no empty constructor' means ?

Comment: @njzk2 I do not, I have only been learning java for 1 week, using tutorials.

Comment: @A--C I will add the code for the music class if you could help.

Comment: @A--C  That would be good, But unfortunately my university thought it would be better to throw us into android and not java.

Comment: @Thomas It doesn't mean that you can't do some research. Just because whoever designed the course assumed prior knowledge doesn't mean you can't try to figure stuff out. Searching for `empty constructor android` gives you explanations of what an empty constructor is. Yes, it is not tailored to your specific need, but it's not hard to put the knowledge together. A better question would be *"Why does this class need an empty constructor?"*

Comment: ok, let's split it. You know what 'no' means, I assume. 'contructor' should be in your lectures. 'Empty', in this context, means 'that takes no argument'.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define the no argument constructor otherwise the systems doesn't know how to instantiate it. Dalvik VM looking for a zero-argument constructor. If you define one argument or more than one in a service.

```
public Music() {
   ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Android instrumentation is trying to create an instance of `com.example.famouspeople.Music` and for that it needs a default constructor. That is why it has failed. Creating a default constructor, `public com.example.famouspeople.Music(){}` in the Music class could help.

```
public class Music implements OnCompletionListener{
  public Music ()
  {
  }
  public boolean  setFileDescriptor(FileDescriptor fileDescriptor){
    //set file descriptor for the current instance
  }
  public boolean   init(){
    //do initialisation of player
  }
}
```

call `init()` after setting file descriptor. But the whole naming conventions seems confusing for your package/classes.